# Why is "had started " used in this example?

Tags: past-tense

I was going to Italy": Do you mean that "In the past you **had started** a journey to Italy, but it wasn't completed." Or do you mean "I was planning a trip to Italy, but cancelled it. I.e. 'I was going to go to Italy'."

Why "had started" and not "started" Is it for emphasizing the journey because it is obvious than it happened before it was not completed . Is it because "in the past" but I ve seen this expression many times  with past simple . In this case it refers to a specific moment (the journey)

Answer (score 1):

we need to understand what function past perfect tense serves to answer this question. in that spirit:

> The past perfect refers to a time earlier than before now. It is used
> to make it clear that one event happened before another in the past.
> It does not matter which event is mentioned first - the tense makes it
> clear which one happened first. when I arrived in the office.

To put it in simple terms: we need it to indicate the sequence of actions (i.e. what happened first and what occurred afterwards.) So it stands to reason to state that you need at least 2 actions, one of which takes place before the others, and which is expressed through past perfect. coming back to the sentence you mention we could identify "starting a journey" as action number 1 and "not completing it" as action number 2. obviously action number 1 took place before action number 2 (rather lack of an action), so past perfect is quite appropriate here.

Nevertheless, it is quite possible to do away with past perfect altogether! whatever can be expressed with past perfect can be expressed using past simple as well (granted, it'll be less precise). people generally don't have a hard time figuring out the sequence of actions even without past perfect. however, as I said past perfect reduces ambiguity and ramps up the clarity of sentences.

Comment: But here there is no ambiguity  so what additionnal information  brings past perfect ?

Comment: but here past simple is as precised and clear  as past perfect could be  because it is obvious the journey was the first action